# boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> is closed before read

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost

I'm trying to write synchronous ssl client. Here is my code:

```
class CHttpsSession
{
public:
    CHttpsSession(io_service& io_service, ssl::context &context, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator) :
        m_socket(io_service, context)
    {
        error_code error = error::host_not_found;
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
        {
            m_socket.lowest_layer().close();
            m_socket.lowest_layer().connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }

        if (error)
        {
            throw system_error(error);
        }

        m_socket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
    }

    void sendRequest(CHttpRequest& request)
    {
        write(m_socket, request.getRequest());
    }

    void receiveResponse(CHttpResponse& response)
    {
        streambuf reply;
        error_code error;
        read(m_socket, reply, transfer_all(), error); //here is error received
        if (error && error != error::eof)
            throw system_error(error);
        response.init(reply);
    }

private:
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> m_socket;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        io_service io_service;
        string server = "some server here";
        string port = "some port here";
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(std::string(server), std::to_string(port));
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        ssl::context ctx(io_service, ssl::context_base::sslv23_client);
        ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("path to certificate file");
        ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::context_base::verify_none);
        auto session = new CHttpsSession(io_service, ctx, endpoint_iterator);

        CHttpRequest request;
        CHttpResonse response;
        //request initialization

        session.sendRequest(request);
        session.receiveResponse(response);
    }        
    catch (boost::system::system_error& exc)
    {
        cout<< exc.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But trying to read data from the socket I get following error: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call.

I also use similar code for non-ssl client and it works.

Am I missing something?

**Update:**

Found that only ssl stream is closed: underlying tcp socket is still open, data is available through it, but since it is encrypted, I can't use it.

Comment: Have you checked the certificates are okay, negotiation works? Try with curl/wget/another HTTPS client (`openssl s_client -verify n`) etc. to see what is going wrong. You test program works for me http://paste.ubuntu.com/10614948/

Comment: @sehe, yes, connecting to google works for me to. Actually I'm trying to connect to another application. Can something cause closing ssl session from the server side? Also the same code using poco libraries instead of boost works for the same server.

Comment: Ok, the POCO data point is interesting. Maybe you can trace the negotation phase. The code was just so it was selfcontained and compilable. As such it shows that the issue is with connecting to the particular server.

Comment: It makes me mad. Although `read(m_socket, reply, transfer_all(), error)` returns 10058 error,  buffer is valid and contains server response. So for now I've added condition for 10058 error: `if (error && error != error::eof && error.value() != 10058)`. But I don't understand why read at the same time returns this error and valid data in buffer...

Comment: I guess it's just a short read due to the `transfer_all` policy. Look how I handled it in my source